# "Speaking Downtown" without the preposition at

Tags: prepositions

Reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/huffpost/amazon-executive-bernie-sanders-attack-backfires-084736128.html) there is a line say,

> “So if you want to hear about $15 an hour and health care, **Senator Sanders will be speaking downtown,**” Clark added. “But if you would like to make at least $15 an hour and have good health care, Amazon is hiring.”

So I assume this CEO of the world wide division of Amazon is saying Sanders will speak about the lowest wage and the health care, at downtown, which is defined by Merriam

> 1: of, relating to, or located in the lower part or business center of a city or town

Why isn't there the preposition "at"?

Googling by "speak downtown meaning" didn't produce anything so I think this is not an idiom.

Thank you for your time in advance(m_m).

Comment: Good question! My assumption is that, though "downtown" a single, unhyphenated, word, colloquial English treats it as preposition/noun. For example, "He's speaking down East," is acceptable New Hampshire parlance. Otherwise, I cannot think of indicating location *without* a preposition, e.g., "speaking from home," "speaking at school," "speaking in *camera*,..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Uptown" and "downtown" don't take additional prepositions before them. Nor do "upstairs," "downstairs," "inside," and "outside." This is probably because these started as separate words (up+town, down+stairs), and therefore the prepositional need is met by "up"/"down"/"in"/"out"

> The bedrooms are located upstairs.

> She works downtown.

Comment: Do you have any references  for the idea that “upstairs” started as “up the stairs” etc.? I’d be interested to read more about that sort of evolution.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/downtown), downtown can be an adjective or an adverb. Here is one of the example sentences, where it is an adverb that modifies the verb **work**:

> I work downtown, but I live in the suburbs

In the sentence that you quoted, downtown is an adverb that modifies the verb **speaking**.

[Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/downtown) offers two main usages- as adjective and noun- but later on it does mention the possibility of using downtown as an adjective, however it doesn't provide any examples.